# Paging Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

I have a gridview with page size=4 what I need is how can i make for loop for all rows in grid view not just in the currnt page?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want paging.

Have a look at Grigview Guy. [He has some great examples](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/210_GridView_Custom_Paging.aspx).
If that doesn't help, there is another [example at the codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewCustomPaging.aspx).

I hope these links help you.